# how to write data to socket channel

Tags: java, nio

is there any small working program for recieving from and sending data to client using java nio.

Actually i am unable to write to socket channel but i am able to read the incoming data
how to write data to socket channel

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: "Unable to write" is not a problem description. `SocketChannel.write()` exists and works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write data to a socket channel like so:

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class SocketWrite {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    // create encoder
    CharsetEncoder enc = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder();  

    // create socket channel
    ServerSocketChannel srv = ServerSocketChannel.open();

    // bind channel to port 9001   
    srv.socket().bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(9001));

    // make connection
    SocketChannel client = srv.accept(); 

    // UNIX line endings
    String response = "Hello!\n";

    // write encoded data to SocketChannel
    client.write(enc.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(response)));

    // close connection
    client.close();
  }
}
```

The [InetSocketAddress](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) may vary depending on what you're connecting to.

Comment: Thanks John,
Thanks for your support yhis is one of the excellent program.
My mistake was I didi not use "\n" at the end of my string...

Comment: Be careful, it is platform dependent.

Comment: Hi John Can u mention on which platform socket channel does not work.

Comment: By platform dependent I was referring to the newline "\n". If you would like a platform independent solution you can use System.getProperty("line.separator")

Comment: Hi John how to know whether the client is disconnected before writing to the socket channel

Comment: `client.write` might not write the entire buffer. You should loop it until the buffer is exhausted.