# how to write char array to java socketchannel

Tags: java, socketchannel

how to write char array to java socketchannel. I am not able to write the char data to socketchannel as it takes ByteBuffer.

Comment: Please provide some code to your question.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871870/how-to-write-data-to-socket-channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [putChar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putChar%28char%29) method of ByteBuffer?

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

for (char ch : myChars) {
  buf.putChar(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways eg

```
char[] c = {'1', '2'};
String str = new String(c);
ByteBuffer bb = Charset.defaultCharset().encode(str);
```

or

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(str.getBytes());
```

Comment: Only comment, more than likely you'll want to be explicit about what character set you are using to encode your character array instead of just using the default charset. Your server is probably expecting a specific one, and you don't want to be prey to the whims of whichever platform and locale is running your code.